# How to export via FTP a MySQL database from phpmyadmin in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, cron

I have a C/C++ application that runs on Ubuntu and save data in a MySQL database named "island".
I would like to send a copy of the whole database at a specified time (during the night for example) via FTP and save it on my remote server.

Should I use cron or would it be better to use C++ code inside my application to do the same operation?
Unfortunately, I never did operations like this one in C++, so can you suggest me how to implement such thing, please?

Comment: _"Should I use cron"_ - yes.  _"or would it be better to use C++ code"_ - **no**

Comment: You should use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to export the database to a file (really just a text file containing the CREATE & INSERT statements needed to import your database). Then you can ftp the file.